# DataGrid + TableAdapter связаный с Базой Данных

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid

Есть база данных (ID, FirstName, SecondName). Подключаю ее к приложению WPF в источники данных. Перетаскиваю на форму и получаю `DataGrid` с отображенными данными из базы. При этом автоматом генерируется `DataSet, TableAdapter и ViewSource.` (множество примеров и видео в интернете)

```
fitnessClubDataSet = ((test_workDB.FitnessClubDataSet)(this.FindResource("fitnessClubDataSet")));
// Загрузить данные в таблицу Employee. Можно изменить этот код как требуется.
fitnessClubDataSetEmployeeTableAdapter = new test_workDB.FitnessClubDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeeTableAdapter();
fitnessClubDataSetEmployeeTableAdapter.Fill(fitnessClubDataSet.Employee);
employeeViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("employeeViewSource")));
employeeViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

Для DataGrid ставлю `ReadOnly = true`. Удаляю столбец ID (пользователю видеть его лишне)

Поместил кнопки "Добавить", "Изменить", "Удалить"

**Добавляем данные:**
Создаем новое окно и помещаем 2 TextBox. По нажатию кнопки ОК выполняется следующий код:

```
fitnessClubDataSetEmployeeTableAdapter.InsertNewImployee(firstNameTextBox.Text, secondNameTextBox.Text);
fitnessClubDataSetEmployeeTableAdapter.Fill(fitnessClubDataSet.Employee);
fitnessClubDataSetEmployeeTableAdapter.Update(fitnessClubDataSet);
```

**Изменяем данные:**

В новом окне так же 2 TextBox. А как получить значение столбцов FirstName и SecondName выбранной строки что-бы отобразить в этих TextBox?

Comment: _"как получить значение столбцов FirstName и SecondName"_ -- надо в xаml окна у TextBox'ов определить {Binding ...} для привязки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работа с Базой Данных через TableAdapter

**Добавляем новые данные**

```
 wwdbDataSet.UsersRow newRow = wwdbDataSet.Users.NewUsersRow();
 newRow.FirstName = "test";
 newRow.SecondName = "test";
 this.wwdbDataSet.Users.Rows.Add(newRow);
 this.userTableAdapter.Update(this.wwdbDataSet.Users);
```

**Изменяем существующие данные**

```
int id = ((this.dgView.SelectedItem as System.Data.DataRowView).Row as wwdbDataSet.UsersRow).Id;
wwdbDataSet.UsersRow dr = wwdbDataSet.Users.FindById(id);
dr.FirstName = "New Name";
dr.SecondName = "New Second Name";
userTableAdapter.Update(dr);
```

**Удаляем данные**

```
if (this.dgView.SelectedItem != null)
 {
 // Определяем id выделенного элемента
 int id = ((this.dgView.SelectedItem as System.Data.DataRowView).Row as wwdbDataSet.UsersRow).Id;
 // Ищем строчку по ID
 wwdbDataSet.UsersRow dr = wwdbDataSet.Users.FindById(id);
 dr.Delete();
 userTableAdapter.Update(wwdbDataSet.Users);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как теперь добавлять/изменять/удалять данные в базе данных?

Обновление базы данных происходит, если вызвать TableAdapter.Update.
В MSDN см. ["Практическое руководство. Обновление данных с помощью адаптера таблицы"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171933.aspx)

Comment: Это не то. Подправил вопрос, думаю так будет понятней