# При добавлении в таблицу SQL-server новых данных вывести эти данные в WPF приложении

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sql-server, entity-framework

Я искал в Google, но даже не знаю как правильно сформулировать данные. Нашёл TriggerContext c# но мне кажется что это не совсем то. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что можно использовать для этого. И если возможно, примеры.

Проблема - В базе есть таблица Заказы. При добавлении нового заказа от клиента нужно вывести информацию о заказе в виде объекта класса Заказ. 
Благодарю заранее!

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476576/datagrid-tableadapter-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%91%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85

Comment: Насколько я помню, вам нужно `SqlDependency`.

Answer (score -1):

Добавим элемент DataGrid в приложение WPF

```
        <DataGrid Name="dgInsuranceTypes" SelectionMode="Single">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ид" Binding="{Binding [Id]}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding [Name]}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Тариф(%)" Binding="{Binding [Tariff]}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Объявим следующие переменные:

```
// Для заполнения DataGrid
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataSet ds;
```

Осталось всего ничего - sql запрос

```
strTbl = "InsuranceTypes";
da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT Id, Name, Tariff FROM " + strTbl, conn);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, strTbl);
dgInsuranceTypes.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[strTbl].DefaultView;
```